# conda install -c from a channel gives me a different version from the website

Tags: command-line-interface, conda, conda-forge

**This question is about conda install command** instead of scikit-learn itself.

I ran `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn` expecting version 0.24.0 as shown on the [Anaconda Cloud conda-forge webpage](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn).

But `conda list` is showing that the version is 0.23.2 and the channel field is empty (I expected the channel field to be conda-forge).

Is there some conda install config that I'm messing up? How come the `-c conda-forge` flag doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: In the "Channel" column from `conda list`, are most of your packages `conda-forge` or blank?

Comment: Some are conda-forge, most are blank. I'd say 25% are conda-forge.

Answer (score 2):

If you require a specific version, then specify it:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn=0.24
```

The issue here is that Conda first tries a frozen install, which entails checking to see if any versions of `scikit-learn` are available that do not require updating any packages already in your environment. Apparently, version `0.23.2` was already perfectly aligned to your existing packages, whereas `0.24` requires changing your existing package versions.

Alternatively, let it install the easiest version, then update:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
conda update -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```